# What is the eyeball icon over the troops in Rome 2 Total War?

Tags: rome-2-total-war

What is the eyeball icon over the troops in Rome 2 Total War?  It is over the troops in battle, and it turns on and off.

Answer (score 1):

The presence of the eye on a unit's banner indicates that unit is not currently visible to any enemy units.  When the eyeball icon is absent from a unit's banner, there is at least one enemy unit that can see that unit of yours.

From twel70's Beginner's Guide to Total War Rome 2 on the Romanian Steam Community page, in the Line of Sight (LoS) section. [Link](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?l=romanian&id=470231187)

In some older Total War games, units that could hide in forests would be shown as hidden by a small tree icon.